# why component re-render again even with useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, function, rerender, usecallback

I have a User Page that fetch the user info with a custom hook `useFetchUserId()`.
This custom hook uses `useEffect` to fetch the data, and has a console.log that is printed every time I switch between tabs, even if I use the `useCallback` hook. Can you explain why, and how to fix it?

**UserProfile page:**

```
  const location = useLocation();
  const userId = location.state?.userId;
  const [tab, setTab] = useState("1");
  const { user, loading } = useFetchUserId(userId);

  const handleTabChange = useCallback(function handleTabChange(event, newTab) {
    setTab(newTab);
  }, []);

  return (
          <TabList onChange={handleTabChange} aria-label="lab API tabs example">
            <Tab label="Info" value="1" />
            <Tab label="Cambia Password" value="2" />
            <Tab label="Curriculum" value="3" />
          </TabList>
```

**useFetchUserId:**

```
 export const useFetchUserId = (id) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  console.log("fetch  " + id);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {

      try {
        const response = await axios....
        const result = response?.data;
        if (result) {
          setUser(result);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } 
    };
    fetch();
    
  }, []);

  return { user, loading };
};
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you're modifying the state of your component so it needs to rerender

Comment: ok, it's true. Can I avoid to call the useFetchUserId, when I change tab? Maybe handle the tabs state in a different component?

Comment: The problem probably lies within useFetchUserId: its useEffect should be modified to only fetch on the right conditions. Can you show its code ?

Comment: I just Updated the code

Comment: Nothing looks wrong in your useFetchUserId, I think your UserProfile must be getting unmounted for some reason. You can verify that by adding `useEffect(() => {
   console.log("Mounting");
   return () => console.log("Unmounting");
}, []);`

Comment: No it does not. only when I first open the Profile page the console is:
"fetch user"
"fetch user"
"Mounting"
"Unmounting"
"Mounting".

Then when I swith tab, same beavior. re-render 2 times

Comment: There's something wrong if you see Unmounting being logged, that means the useEffect will be retriggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change state by `setTab(newTab)`. It triggers re-render (aka re-execution of component function). This way your hook `useFetchUserId` is executed every time. This is why you see a console log multiple times. See the console.log outside of `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

Check what are you send dependencies in `useEffect`, if use `user` as dependency remove this

Comment: His dependencies list of `useEffect` is empty. That's not a reason.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).